# RewriteRule not working with NGINX Reverse Proxy for Apache Server

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a huge amount URLs that needed to redirect to a single page. on a Cpanel server, I am using this code in .htaccess for redirect anything after /my-links/ to /new-page.

```
RewriteRule ^/?old-links/.+ /new-page/ [R=301,L]
```

I want to do the same thin my other server that has Nginx as a Web Server and Reverse Proxy for Apache. I used the same code in .htaccess but the redirect not working. 
 In my Apache config I have enabled allowoverride all and my Nginx config like this

```
server_name       domain.com www.domain.com;

root /home/username/public_html/;
index index.php index.htm index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_pass http://ip:8080$request_uri;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have converted .htaccess code to Nginx redirect code and it's working fine now.

```
rewrite ^/?old-links/.+ /new-links;
```